# Single-line scrolling in gnome-terminal broken?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal, scrolling

[The GNOME documentation](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/gnome-terminal-usage.html.en) says that I should be able to scroll my gnome-terminal output by one line using CTRL-SHIFT-(up/down).  Neither works for me; I get A or B, which I assume has to do with the control sequences that the up/down arrows produce.

Is this incompatible with bash / zsh command history, or is there something more sinister at work?  Moreover, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[No it doesn't](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal) (you're looking at the documentation for the wrong version of GNOME Terminal).

Answer (score 2):

I get A or B when press only SHIFT+up/down.

CTRL+SHIFT+up/down on Ubuntu 10.04 work

Comment: This is a RHEL system; I've tried both SHIFT+up/down and CTRL+SHIFT+up/down; both give A or B, and don't scroll.  Maybe something is eating the "CTRL"?